# Background crashes reported in app on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

We see high number of crashes being reported on Google Play in our app. And more than 99% of these are background crashes. See attached screenshot

[image]

Unfortunately, there is not much information available in stacktrace, nothing really that connect to our code.

Here are the stacktraces for top 3 issues in the screenshot above

1. **Missing information
   SIGABRT**

```
Check failed: runtime == nullptr || !runtime->IsStarted() || runtime->IsShuttingDown(self_)

*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 14204 >>> com.myapp.NameChanged <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x0000000000000654
```

2. ***[libart.so] art::gc::Heap::StartGC(art::Thread*, art::gc::GcCause, art::gc::CollectorType) SIGSEGV**

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 22755 >>> com.myapp.NameChanged <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x00000000003eef08  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::StartGC(art::Thread*, art::gc::GcCause, art::gc::CollectorType)+68)
  #01  pc 0x00000000002e8050  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::ScopedGCCriticalSection::ScopedGCCriticalSection(art::Thread*, art::gc::GcCause, art::gc::CollectorType)+44)
  #02  pc 0x0000000000015504  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libperfetto_hprof.so (perfetto_hprof::DumpPerfetto(art::Thread*)+96)
  #03  pc 0x000000000001e134  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libperfetto_hprof.so (void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, ArtPlugin_Initialize::$_34> >(void*)+328)
  #04  pc 0x00000000000e5a08  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+208)
  #05  pc 0x000000000000227c
```

3. **[libart.so] __aarch64_cas4_rel
   SIGBUS**

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 30902 >>> com.myapp.NameChanged <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x000000000025cc10  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (__aarch64_cas4_rel+16)
  #01  pc 0x00000000003ef324  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::StartGC(art::Thread*, art::gc::GcCause, art::gc::CollectorType)+1120)
  #02  pc 0x00000000002e8050  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::ScopedGCCriticalSection::ScopedGCCriticalSection(art::Thread*, art::gc::GcCause, art::gc::CollectorType)+44)
  #03  pc 0x0000000000015504  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libperfetto_hprof.so (perfetto_hprof::DumpPerfetto(art::Thread*)+96)
  #04  pc 0x000000000001e134  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libperfetto_hprof.so (void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, ArtPlugin_Initialize::$_34> >(void*)+328)
  #05  pc 0x00000000000ba5a8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+208)
  #06  pc 0x0000000000001e9c
```

Majority of these issues are on Android 13 and 12 and on Samsung devices like A52, S20, S22 etc.

Worst, we don't see them on our test devices. Tried multiple scenarios, including putting App in background for long time.

Need help/any pointer on -

**Based on the little information, how should we approach them to solve? Is there any way we can link this stacktrace info to our code? Is there any way we can add some additional code to the app and catch them like normal exception?**
I am following [this link](https://source.android.com/docs/core/tests/debug/native-crash) to understand the issues but we can no way have access to user devices to fetch logs so not helping much.

Thank you.